# Run command on Rails Console startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to run a specific command when the rails console starts? I'd like it to print out whether or not I'm connected to the remote or local database in BIG LETTERS! I don't mind writing a custom method to determine that– I'm just asking how to write to the console. I've seen errors and alerts there before.

For example: `rails c` prints out `Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.11)
**USING REMOTE DATABASE** 1.9.3p125 :001 >`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write ruby code in `irb` config file. Edit the `.irbrc` file and add your ruby code used to determine whether you connected to local or remote

```
if defined? Rails
   //ruby code to find you connected to local or remote
   puts "USING REMOTE DATABASE...."
end
```